# Getting MT5209 Error In Xamarin iOS Application for Google Maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm writing an application for Android and iOS using Xamarin, I need to use the Maps feature and get the location of the user to give them information on surrounding areas, however I want to display custom markers so I can't use the native Maps API because custom markers will then only work for Android.

I've seen there is a Google Maps for iOS Component in Xamarin and have tried to add this to my project and do what it says, however every time I build I get the following error.

> Error MT5209: Native linking error: file not found:
>   /Users/Zach/Documents/Development/Project/project-app/Project/Project.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleMaps
>   (MT5209) (Project.iOS)

Please note I've changed wherever my actual project name is with Project for privacy reasons.

I've looked on the Xamarin forums and there are a few posts about this particular error however none of their solutions seem to be working for me. The project built once at the start after adding Google Maps but ever since I've had the same error.

I am running Xamarin Studio on a MacBook Pro.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Its a "file not found", but what file? the error message doesn't say. Unless GoogleMaps doesn't have a file extension. You could use ProcessMonitor (FileMon) to trace when you are building and pinpoint the file it's looking for. Also since it's supposed to reside in the **obj** folder you know its created during a build and this leads me to suspect your missing a reference of some kind. Just a guess but the Filemon trace should help you find out what file(s) are missing.

Comment: It is the GoogleMaps file that is missing, it doesn't have an extension, problem is I've followed everything correctly, I have the NuGet package and the Component added, and my project setup looks the same as the example, which works everytime, the only difference being that my GoogleMaps file doesn't get created and theirs does.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide a bare bones example or better a link to download your code/project/solution. I trust you have followed the example to the letter but without the cut down example for us to reproduce the problem it will be much harder to do root cause analysis and provide an answer to your problem. Have you tried building the sample and copying the file to your solution? Set its permissions so it can't be deleted, build, and tell us what the next error is?

Comment: I've decided to use Mapbox instead now, which is working wonderfully.

Comment: Put that as an answer so everyone knows your problem is solved